# React error: 'values' is not defined, no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a request form using NPX create-react-app. The app has six components: UserForm (act as container) RequestType, UserDetails, PaymentDetails, Confirmation and Success. There are three request types for user to choose in RequestType component. Depending on user's selection, Payment Details component will render different fields for user to fill out. Consequently the Confirmation component needs to display different items in line with whats been rendered in Payment Details component.

I get 'values' is not defined error in my Confirmation component (code provided below). I used ES6 restructuring to pull values out from `this.props` and thought I had defined 'values.

The `<p>` tags are just a placeholder in the following code and I will have some JSX tags go in there once the error is gone.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Confirm extends Component {
    continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
      };
    back = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
     };
    render() {
    const {values: {request, empName, empPersonnelNo, postName, postNumber...more items but are
                omitted here}
               } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            {values.request==="actingUp" && <p>You are requesting acting up payments</p>}
        </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please give an actual [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have destructed the variable `values`. First get `values` and then destruct it.

```
const {values} = this.props
const {request, empName, empPersonnelNo, postName, postNumber...more items but are
                omitted here} = values
```

Or

```
return (
        <div>
            {request==="actingUp" && <p>You are requesting acting up payments</p>}
        </div>
        )
```

Instead of

```
return (
        <div>
            {values.request==="actingUp" && <p>You are requesting acting up payments</p>}
        </div>
        )
```

Comment: By chance I figured out by removing values from 'values.request' I got the desired result but I did not know why it worked. Thank you so much Alexander Vidaurre Arroyo for your clear explanation, now I understand why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @jonrsharpe for trying to help me. I don't actually know how to construct a minimal reproducible example because my code is rather conveluted. However I have somehow found a solution to my problem - by removing 'values' from 'values.request ==="actingUP', the code appears to be producing desired results. I don't know why it worked though. Once again, thank you..